# Inserting data to dropdown comboboxes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am a fairly new to visual studio.   I have 2 forms with dropdown cb_CBOX1 & dropdown list cb_CBOX2.
I want user to add data to cb_CBOX1 and have the data be inserted in alphabetical order in cb_CBOX1 dropdown and be inserted in alphabetical order in cb_CBOX2 dropdown list also.

I'm trying to use the below statement.  TIA

```
cb_CBOX2.Items.Add(cb_CBOX1.Text)
```

Update 2017-11-07:

I have 2 forms both have combobox with drop down list. I want user to insert data to cb_CBOX1 and have the data added alphabetically to the cb_CBOX1 drop down and added alphabetically to cb_CBOX2 drop down.  When the user types in data in cb_CBOX1, they will click button1 to call the Add function.

My code:

```
Private Sub button1.Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

    cb_CBOX2.Items.Add (cb_CBOX1.Text) 

End Sub
```

Comment: not sure I understand your question properly. What is the second form doing? What is "data be inserted alpha"? What do you mean?

Comment: What's the question?  When are you calling the Add function?  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the items, add the new item, sort, then apply the items back. It's fairly simple with Linq.

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    addToAndSortComboBox(cb_CBOX1, cb_CBOX1.Text)
    addToAndSortComboBox(cb_CBOX2, cb_CBOX1.Text)
    cb_CBOX1.Text = "" ' optional
End Sub

Private Sub addToAndSortComboBox(cb As ComboBox, value As String)
    Dim items = cb.Items.Cast(Of String).Concat({value}).OrderBy(Function(v) v).ToList()
    cb.Items.Clear()
    cb.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray())
End Sub
```

Just a comment on the design: it doesn't seem very intuitive. I feel like the input should be done in a TextBox with the ComboBoxes having `ComboBox.DropDownStyle = DropDownList`.

Comment: While the above code did work for my Application, the data that is input is removed from the cb_CBOX1 & cb_CBOX2 when the Application is closed.  I need to have the data added to the cb's and be permanently added to the dropdownlist in cb_CBOX1 & cb_CBOX2

Comment: Yes of course. How do you store persistent data in your application?

Comment: Persistent data is stored in dropdown list cb_CBOX1 & cb_CBOX2.

Comment: No, that data goes away when the application closes so it's not persistent. You need some sort of file or database to store the information somewhere outside of the program's memory space! Look at XML, SQL, and user settings for example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be able to add data to a list, Whatever the user types into combobox1, will appear on combobox2 on a different window?

I'd suggest binding your combo boxes to a list, and then setting the item-sources of both combo-boxes to this list.

Create the list, and reference it in a class so you can access it from a different window...

```
Dim comboboxitemlist As New List(Of String)
```

Bind your list to CB2...

```
cb_CBOX2.itemssource = comboboxitemlist
```

In a button or however you are adding...

```
comboboxitemlist.add(cb_cbox1.text)
```

Comment: The question doesn't look like WPF.